# Positioning absolute element relative to viewport

Tags: javascript, math, slider, viewport, absolute

I'm making a slider from scratch and I'm having an issue with the absolute positioning which has to be relative to the viewport (whenever the window height changes). Basically the slider has a bar and a button (to slide) and I wrote code to get the relative button position to the bar:

```
const getRelativeCoordinates = (event, referenceElement) => {

   const position = {
     x: event.pageX,
     y: event.pageY
   };

   const offset = {
     left: referenceElement.offsetLeft,
     top: referenceElement.offsetTop
   };

   return { 
     x: position.x - offset.left,
     y: position.y - offset.top,
   }; 
}
```

and I wrote code to know after a cursor slide where the button would change his position and what percentage 1-100 actually is:

```
  const handleSlider = (e) => {
    const sliderBar = document.getElementById('slider-bar')
    const sliderBtn = document.getElementById('slider-button')

    const sliderHeight = parseInt(sliderBar.getBoundingClientRect().height) - sliderBarOffsetY
    const cursorY = getRelativeCoordinates(e, document.getElementById('slider-bar')).y
    let slidingPerc = ((sliderHeight - cursorY) / sliderHeight) * 100

    if (slidingPerc > 100) slidingPerc = 100
    else if (slidingPerc < 0) slidingPerc = 0

    let barPerc = sliderBarMaxY - ((slidingPerc * (sliderBarMaxY - sliderBarMinY)) / 100)

    return {
      barPerc,
      slidingPerc
    }
  }
```

The problem is that `sliderBarMaxY` and `sliderBarMinY` (83 and 9) are constants of max and min values of the button absolute top position in percentage (83% and 9%). These values changing the viewport height would not work anymore and if I try to change them by `window.innerHeight` (83 : 460 = x : `innerHeight`) gives an offset-error (in my case of 17)

Comment: Don't use `position: absolute` if you need it relative to the viewport? Consider using `position: fixed` instead? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: the root is 100vh

Comment: btw I don't want the slider fixed to the viewport

Comment: I don't care about sliders, but I too want to position an absolute div to x, y coordinates in the viewport, viewport-relative positioning. Can't find an answer.